# A cowboy rodeo riddle

Tags: situation, time

First, the cowboy went to the rodeo on Monday.
Three days later, he went back home on Friday.
Can you solve it?

> Is it Friday or Thursday?

Comment: There are several possible answers, each depending on a different application of xkcd-169, and a couple more using the answers to the recently very popular twin paradoxes.  A question will fare much better on this site, if it has a unique solution, easily identifiable as such when seen.

Comment: how is this off-topic? after all, riddles are puzzling questions

Comment: Either the horse is named Monday or it is named Friday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is:

> It's Friday, he rode in on a horse named Monday and on the day called Tuesday.

Alternatively:

> It also could be neither, if Friday and Monday are both horses, but there really isn't any clue to say which day it is among these.

Answer (score 2):

It's a classic:

> His horse is named Friday, so the day must be a Thursday.

Answer (score 1):

*I* think that

> He had a horse named "Monday," went to the rodeo, where there was a...

wait for it...

> *Horse Sale*, then he bought a horse, named it "Friday," and returned the same day.  So the day was ***"Horse Selling day."*** (which, everybody knows, is Thursday.)

Answer (score 0):

Is it.

> He went to rodeo on Monday at 11.59 midnight and went back home at 12.00 AM on Thursday which is Friday. The total time difference will be 3days and 1 minute. One minute is negligible while calculating time in days ?.

Answer (score 0):

it is

> Friday

he went to the rodeo on Monday

> Monday is the name of a boat that carries him to the rodeo across time ones on Monday between 11-midnight and while crossing timezones he arrives at the rodeo during Tuesday on Monday.

three days later he returns home on Friday

> Friday is another boat that he boarded on Thursday between 11-midnight and while crossing timezones, he returns on Friday during Friday.