# A cowboy rides into town on Friday. He stays for three days and then leaves on Friday. How did he do it

Tags: riddle

This question has probably been found off the internet by teachers trying to get their students brains thinking so it shouldn't be too hard if it is for kids.

Comment: This is pretty much a duplicate of [cowboy rodeo riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/63138/cowboy-rodeo-riddle)

Comment: @Deusovi You edited the tags, but it's not a [tag:riddle] either :-)

Answer (score 2):

He is

> riding a horse named friday