# So, you are a horse rider and riding on Friday. The next day, it is Wednesday. How is this possible?

Tags: riddle

So, you are a horse rider and riding on Friday. The next day, it is Wednesday. How is this possible?

Comment: This has been asked before: [cowboy rodeo riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/63138/cowboy-rodeo-riddle)

Comment: But the other is closed as "not suitable for this site", which I don't understand btw.  And this one has a better formulation.

Answer (score 2):

You are riding on Friday, so
the horse is named Friday.

Comment: Alternatively, the horse could be named Wednesday (the 'it' referring to the horse, instead of the day). Or even the horse was named Friday, and you (the horse owner) renamed it to Wednesday.

Comment: @MatthewJensen ...or you have two horses named Friday and Wednesday respectively...

Comment: ... or Wednesday is your pal who rides Friday on the next day, which could be a Monday.